# Prove that $a_n$ is a Cauchy sequence, if $|a_{n+1} - a_n| < \frac{1}{n(n+1)}$

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, sequences-and-series

Obviously, $\frac{1}{n(n+1)}$ converges to $0$, as $n \to \infty$
But it doesn't say anything to me, since, for example, $a_n = \sqrt{n}$ diverges, but $|a_{n+1} - a_n| \to 0$
So I need to look at this problem from another point of view.

Sequence is Cauchy, if $$(\forall \varepsilon >0)(\exists N \in \mathbb{N})(\forall n \geq N)(\forall m \geq N): |a_n - a_m| < \varepsilon$$
Now considering some inequalities:

1. $|a_{n}   - a_{n+1}| < \frac{1}{(n)  (n+1)} = \frac{1}{n}   - \frac{1}{n+1}$
2. $|a_{n+1} - a_{n+2}| < \frac{1}{(n+1)(n+2)} = \frac{1}{n+1} - \frac{1}{n+2}$
3. $|a_{n+2} - a_{n+3}| < \frac{1}{(n+2)(n+3)} = \frac{1}{n+2} - \frac{1}{n+3}$ etc.

Adding them:
$|a_n - a_{n+3}| \leq |a_{n}   - a_{n+1}| + |a_{n+1} - a_{n+2}| + |a_{n+2} - a_{n+3}| < \frac{1}{n}   - \frac{1}{n+1} + \frac{1}{n+1} - \frac{1}{n+2} + \frac{1}{n+2} - \frac{1}{n+3} = \frac{1}{n} - \frac{1}{n+3}$

And that makes me assume, that $|a_n - a_m| < \frac{1}{n \times m}$ (if it is a correct assumption, induction is needed to prove it, I guess)
Hence, in order to make $|a_n - a_m| < \varepsilon$, we need to ensure that $n \times m > \frac{1}{\varepsilon}$

But I would like to have only $n$ on the left side.
So, besides the need to prove that $a_n$ is a Cauchy sequence, I have four additional questions:

1. Is my reasoning correct?
2. If it is, then do we need to get rid of $m$ (since $m$ is not a fixed number).
3. If we do, how to do that?
4. If we are talking about basic Cauchy sequences, is tag "sequences-and-series" appropriate?

Thank you

Edit:
instead of $|a_n - a_m| < \frac{1}{n \times m}$ there should be $|a_n - a_m| < \frac{1}{n} - \frac{1}{m}$

Comment: It is not true that $|a_n - a_m| < \frac{1}{n \times m}$. Your steps suggest that $|a_n - a_m| < \frac{1}{n} - \frac{1}{ n+m}$, prove it rigorously by induction.

Comment: @StratosFair oh, indeed, if we take $m = n+p$, then $|a_n - a_{n+p}| < \frac{p}{n(n+p)}$. Thank you

Comment: @StratosFair It should be $\frac{1}{n}-\frac{1}{m}$, even though the formula you stated is true, since $\frac{1}{m+n}<\frac{1}{m}$. Maybe you meant to write $|a_n-a_{n+m}|$

Comment: Right @Didier, I noticed my mistake after reading your answer, thanks for the comment !

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For $n<m$, write
$$
a_n-a_m = \sum_{k=n}^{m-1}a_k-a_{k+1},
$$
so that the triangle inequality yields
$$
|a_n-a_m| \leqslant \sum_{k=n}^{m-1}|a_k-a_{k+1}|.
$$
From what you have done, you should find
$$
|a_n-a_m| \leqslant \frac{1}{n}-\frac{1}{m} \leqslant \frac{1}{n},
$$
and the result should come up easily now.
This is the so called trick of [telescoping series](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Telescoping_series), and getting rid of $m$ is easier than you thought here.